# How to add memory to an ARM Cortex Microcontroller

Tags: arm, memory, firmware

I am looking into a design that would use the ARM Cortex M4F core but am just the software engineer for the project. The EE tells me that there will be an 64 MByte sdram memory module connected to the chip. After looking at the datasheets I don't understand how I am suppose to access that memory space. Does the EMC make that space globally available to the firmware without any modification? I'm not even really sure I'm asking the question correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What processor (mfg and part#)? What compiler are you using?

Comment: The processor is the NXP LPC4088 and we are still deciding on a compiler. It will either be GCC, ARM-CC, or IAR

Comment: Did you read the EMC chapter of the user manual? (the datasheet contains general and electronic information, the user manual is what you need to program the chip.)

Comment: AFAIK the LPC4088 is similar to the more popular LPC1788, which has a Cortex M3 core.  Which might help you to find more information/examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find out where the EMC maps to in the memory map section of the datasheet/reference manual. Once you have the address range, you will need to setup your linker to use that space for either data memory or a specific section in which you can locate your data.

If you use IAR, this will be in your `.icf` file. You can specify the section to place a variable in by using `#pragma location = "SectionName"`.